# Sqlite Error while creating a table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Why i am getting the sqlite error ,any help appreciated

```
public static final String KEY_ORDERID="id_order";
    public static final  String KEY_SUBTRUCKID="id_subtruck";
    public static final  String KEY_TRUCK_NUMBER="id_trucknmbr";

private static final String CREATE_MASTER_TRUCK_DETAIL = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_MASTER_DATA + " ("
            + KEY_SUBTRUCKID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ORDERID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL"+")";

    private static final String CREATE_SLAVE_TRUCK_DETAIL = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_SLAVE_DATA+ " ("
        + KEY_ORDERID + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_TRUCK_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_SUBTRUCKID+") REFERENCES "
        +TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_MASTER_DATA+" ("+KEY_SUBTRUCKID+"))";
```

Log error:

```
 unknown column "id_subtruck" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE truckslave (id_order INTEGER,id_trucknmbr TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (id_subtruck) REFERENCES truckmaster (id_subtruck))
```

Comment: There is `Create` statement inside a Create statement after REFERENCES which is an invalid sql syntax.

Comment: The part `+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_SUBTRUCKID+") REFERENCES "` is wrong. Because in the table there is no such column named `KEY_SUBTRUCKID`. You have to add that column

Comment: @GVillani82 i had added this column on my master table CREATE_MASTER_TRUCK_DETAIL

Answer (score 0):

Change `CREATE_MASTER_TRUCK_DETAIL` to `TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_MASTER_DATA`in `CREATE_SLAVE_TRUCK_DETAIL` :

```
    private static final String CREATE_SLAVE_TRUCK_DETAIL = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_SLAVE_DATA+ " ("
    + KEY_ORDERID + " INTEGER,"
    + KEY_TRUCK_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_SUBTRUCKID_SLAVE + " TEXT,"//Define new column which would be the foreign key
    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_SUBTRUCKID_SLAVE+") REFERENCES "
    + TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_MASTER_DATA +" ("+KEY_SUBTRUCKID+"))";
```

I think by mistakely you have appended the *create statement of the master table* in place of **master table name**.

As pointed by @GVillani82 you must define a column in `TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_SLAVE_DATA` which will be referencing the `KEY_SUBTRUCKID` column of `TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_MASTER_DATA`.

Comment: now it's throwing this error...unknown column "id_subtruck" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE truckslave (id_order INTEGER,id_trucknmbr TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (id_subtruck) REFERENCES truckmaster (id_subtruck))

Comment: You have to add new column to `TABLE_TRUCK_DETAIL_SLAVE_DATA` for mapping foreign key. Note the single line comment in my answer.

Comment: Refer [SQL foreign key tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) for more clarity.